# Asignar valor de una clase con valor tipo LIST a Int Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo la siguiente consulta donde hago un mapeo en linq para luego realizar filtros de los campos, inicialmente tengo el siguiente código y voy a utilizar algo genérico

```
public class ClaseEjemplo
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set;}
    public List<c> cObject {get; set;}
    public List<D> DObject {get; set;}
}
```

en un método realizo la consulta linq...

```
var ClaseMaped = from p in Db.ClaseEjemplo
                                     select new ClaseAMapear
                                     {
                                         A = p.A,
                                         B = p.B,
                                         c = p.cObject,
                                         d = p.DObject,
                                     };
                return ClaseMaped.ToList()
```

pero por razones obvias p.cObject y p.Dobject son list, pero en la ClaseAMapear c es tipo int y d también es de tipo int
Como hago para que los valores de ClaseAMapear se puedan filtrar con ClaseEjemplo?

Comment: Que haria ClaseAMapear, q campos tendrias, cual es el sentido de esta clase

Comment: Además falta saber la estructura de la clase *c* y *d* que especificas en cada lista

Comment: @Japv ClaseAMapear es un DTO

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera creo que tendría que hacer una relación (join) de las clases c y d para obtener el mismo tipo de dato en ClaseAMapear, pero en base de datos no están relacionadas.